# Proving $F$ is the midpoint of a triangle segment.

Tags: geometry

In triangle $ABC$, the points $D$, $E$ and $F$ are on respective segments
$BC$, $CA$ and $AB$. Also assume $AD$, $BE$ and $CF$ are concurrent
(intersecting at a point $P$) and  line $DE$ is parallel to line $AB$.
I have to show $F$ is the midpoint of $AB$.

The only problem I'm having is what does concurrent mean in this problem? Does it just mean an intersection of three line segments or altitudes?

Comment: None: it means those three lines intersect in one single point. They don't have to be altitudes, medians, sides perpendicular bisectors nor angle bisectors: just three lines from each vertex to opposite sides that "concur"...

Comment: As for the parallel lines I end.up getting similar triangles but.then.from here not sure.where to go? I end up getting.three pairs of similar triangles but none of them help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Ceva's Theorem**

$\hspace{5.5cm}$[image]

[Ceva's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva%27s_theorem) says that

$$
\frac{AE}{EC}\frac{CD}{DB}\frac{BF}{FA}=1
$$
Since $DE\,\|\,AB$, similar triangles yields $\frac{AE}{EC}\frac{CD}{DB}=1$, therefore $\frac{BF}{FA}=1$.

---

**Alternate Proof**

$\triangle CTE$ is similar to $\triangle CFA$ and $\triangle CTD$ is similar to $\triangle CFB$. Therefore,
$$
\frac{\overline{TE}}{\overline{FA}}
=\frac{\overline{CT}}{\overline{CF}}
=\frac{\overline{TD}}{\overline{FB}}
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\frac{\overline{FA}}{\overline{FB}}
=\frac{\overline{TE}}{\overline{TD}}\tag{1}
$$
$\triangle BMF$ is similar to $\triangle EMT$ and $\triangle AMF$ is similar to $\triangle DMT$. Therefore,
$$
\frac{\overline{TE}}{\overline{FB}}
=\frac{\overline{TM}}{\overline{FM}}
=\frac{\overline{TD}}{\overline{FA}}
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\frac{\overline{FB}}{\overline{FA}}
=\frac{\overline{TE}}{\overline{TD}}\tag{2}
$$
Putting $(1)$ and $(2)$ together yields
$$
\frac{\overline{FA}}{\overline{FB}}
=\frac{\overline{TE}}{\overline{TD}}
=\frac{\overline{FB}}{\overline{FA}}\tag{3}
$$
$(3)$ implies that $\overline{FA}=\pm\overline{FB}$. Since $\overline{FA}+\overline{FB}=\overline{AB}$ and assuming $\overline{AB}\ne0$, we have
$$
\overline{FA}=\overline{FB}\tag{4}
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Use converse of [Ceva's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva%27s_theorem).

Good luck!

Comment: Why can't this be a comment?

Comment: @mergeme It can, but it shouldn't. AFAIR, the policy is to think of comments as ephemeral in nature. See, for example, [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4623) and [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148).